# Why can't I find 32bit edition of Kubuntu 20.04?

Tags: kubuntu, 20.04

Why can't I find 32bit edition of Kubuntu 20.04?
I have an old laptop and I want to install Kubuntu on it. But I've found out that there is no 32bit version of Kubuntu in the mirror page [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/20.04/release/).
Did Kubuntu drop support for 32bit systems?

Comment: Kubuntu 18.04 LTS was the last with i386 (x86) support. Lubuntu and Xubuntu continued for the 18.10 release, and into the 19.04 cycle but that ceased during Dec-2018.

Comment: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/05/kubuntu-drops-32-bit-installer-images  (I haven't found official notices yet - but look at https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kubuntu-devel/2018-May/011657.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubuntu 18.04 LTS was the last Kubuntu with i386 (x86 32-bit) support.

Xubuntu and Lubuntu continued releases i386 versions of 18.10 releases, and continued with alpha builds of i386 of 19.04 until Dec-2018 (Xubuntu dropped early in December, Lubuntu later in the month).

The best official notice maybe https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kubuntu-devel/2018-May/011657.html,  for a press/blog article (often easier to read in context) maybe read https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/05/kubuntu-drops-32-bit-installer-images

Comment: Possibly because of the alpha builds of 19.04 (Lubuntu & Xubuntu), all builds of i386 continued for the life of 19.04. Builds of packages on *eoan* were however turned off in the days before actual release, so whilst upgrade to *eoan* was possible before release, that door closed & made no sense pretty quickly. If you do need a new build than 18.04 LTS provides, I'd recommend Debian Buster (10) has it provided full x86 (i586 & i686 support; Ubuntu only had i686 dropping i586 some time ago)