# I have a Dell Mini 1010 running lubuntu 18.04

Tags: updates

I would like to upgrade to 20.04 but it seems the atom chip is no longer supported.  Are there other options?

Comment: There are atom cpus that are x86_64, however there are also atom cpus that are x86 only.  eg. I tested Lubuntu x86 releases on a `asus eepc 1000HE (intel atom n270, 1gb, intel mobile 945gse integrated)` which won't run anything past 19.04 (which is now EOL) as it's n270 intel atom is x86 only.  What atom cpu do you have?

Comment: A scan online seems to imply you may have an intel atom z530 which is x86 only.  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is fully-supported until April-2021, with support for the base system continuing for a further two years (April-2023). Any other OSes will be off-topic on this site, however I will state I also test Debian (Buster being latest) on my boxes (including the asus eepc mentioned in prior comment), though I'd stick with Lubuntu and install Debian if you're still using it when you're outside of Ubuntu support time.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 is supported with free [Extended Security Maintenance](https://askubuntu.com/a/1001728/) (ESM) until April, 2028. All you need is an Ubuntu One account.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 12.04 : Should I update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1276755/ubuntu-12-04-should-i-update)

Comment: Maybe additional detail can be read at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243348/why-cant-i-find-32bit-edition-of-kubuntu-20-04/1243351#1243351

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will ESM also become available for Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001714/will-esm-also-become-available-for-ubuntu-14-04)